# In hlsl what this means

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl, fxcomposer

I have some code in .fx file whening using fxcomposer,and I met some code like this:

```
 float4x4 WorldITXf : WorldInverseTranspose < string UIWidget="None"; >
```

what is the < and > containning meaning?

Answer (score 2):

`< string UIWidget="None"; >` is an annotation that is not used by the HLSL complier or Direct3D. It's just used by FXComposer to determine how to provide interactive controls for the shader in tools.

It's an aspect of the legacy Direct3D 9 era Effects system, and was intended to make it easier for Digital Content Creation (DCC) tools like FXComposer, RenderMonkey, [Autodesk 3DS MAX](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_DCFE87C8_8381_49A8_9C2F_067D89E1E3F5_htm), etc. to provide more art-driven UI for controlling shader behavior.

More modern solutions for art-driven shader production have moved away from just having a programmer mark up a shader with 'tweaks', and are more often done with flow diagrams like Visual Studio's [Shader Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315733.aspx)--although VS's solution here is not nearly as robust as say the visual shader designer in Unreal Engine.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173004.aspx)